# Retrieved token gets WordWrapped in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, variables, token, word-wrap

Trying to retrieve a token via PowerShell to PowerBI.
I manage to recieve the token but I guess it's being WordWrapped because using the variable gives me an error. If I copy the string and removes row cuts It works.

How can I prevent the token from being WordWrapped (It prints the value in rows not in one line)?

***My Code - Version 1***

```
    #Username for login in Azure
    $username = "name@domain.com"
    #Password for login in Azure encrypted
    $password = "0100000011100000000020000000000000..."
    #Takes the username and convert the encrypted password and stores them in $cred variable
    $cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username,($password | ConvertTo-SecureString)
    #Uses the credentials to login to PowerBI
    Login-PowerBI -Credential $cred
    #Retrieves the login token that was created at login
    $PowerBIToken = Get-PowerBIAccessToken
    #The token is stored in $PowerBIToken.values but has "Bearer MYTOKEN" format, remove "Bearer " 
    $PowerBIToken = $PowerBIToken.values -replace 'Bearer '
    #Adds " before and after the token since it is required I think to use the token
    $PowerBIToken = "`"$PowerBIToken`""
    #Writes to host the information formatted to verify If it is correct
    Write-Host $PowerBIToken
    #Disconnect the access to PowerBI
    Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount

    Clear-PBITableRows -authToken $PowerBIToken -DataSetId "11111111-7777-ffff-6666-dddddddddddd" -TableName "RealTimeData"
```

***My Code - Version 2***

```
    #Username for login in Azure
    $username = "name@domain.com"
    #Password for login in Azure encrypted
    $password = "0100000011100000000020000000000000..."
    #Takes the username and convert the encrypted password and stores them in $cred variable
    $cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username,($password | ConvertTo-SecureString)
    #Uses the credentials to login to PowerBI
    Login-PowerBI -Credential $cred
    #Retrieves the login token that was created at login
    $PowerBIToken = Get-PowerBIAccessToken
    #Writes to host the information formatted to verify If it is correct
    Write-Host $PowerBIToken.values
    #Disconnect the access to PowerBI
    Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount

    Clear-PBITableRows -authToken $PowerBIToken.values -DataSetId "11111111-7777-ffff-6666-dddddddddddd" -TableName "RealTimeData"
```

***Both versions above gives this error***

```
Invoke-PBIRequest : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. - ''
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerBIPS\PowerBIPS.psm1:1410 char:5
+     Invoke-PBIRequest -authToken $authToken -method Delete -resource  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Net.WebException,Invoke-PBIRequest
```

***Without adding " to the token gives this error***

```
Clear-PBITableRows : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'authToken'. Cannot convert value to type System.String.
At C:\Temp\PowerBI\PowerBI-AccessToken.ps1:12 char:35
+     Clear-PBITableRows -authToken $PowerBIToken -DataSetId "f866e111- ...
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Clear-PBITableRows], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Clear-PBITableRows
```

But if I copy the token string printed on the `Write-Host` command and put it instead of the `$PowerBIToken` variable in the final row `Clear-PBITableRows...` and removes all row cuts (wordWrappes) that command works as intended.

Comment: What does *"WordWrapped"* even mean? Also, explain with an example what `$PowerBIToken.values` contains and what your string replacement/modification should produce from that.

Comment: I improved my question with explanation of WordWrap and $PowerBIToken.values

Comment: Okay, that's a bit clearer to me now. Enclosing the token in double quotes is not necessary, simply remove that line.

Comment: Here is the [source code](https://github.com/DevScope/powerbi-powershell-modules/blob/8edd6ad9bd0532277f7dd4424719f66905eeee8f/Modules/PowerBIPS/PowerBIPS.psm1#L2242) of the function `Invoke-PBIRequest`, which is ultimately using the auth token value in the PowerBI module. See how it re-creates the HTTP request header by putting `Bearer` back in front of the token value. Enclosing your token in double quotes would break that.

Comment: That being said, enclosing a value in double quotes does not work like `"""$value"""` in PowerShell at all. Correct would have been either `"\`"$value\`""` (the backtick is PowerShell's escape character) or `'"' + $value + '"'`.

Comment: If I remove Bearer and adds quotes I get the (403) Forbidden error.
Same thing happends if I just use ```$PowerBIToken.values``` so I will skip the other rows. But the issue persists that It only works when hardcoding the token without row cuts.

Comment: Do not add quotes. Have I been unclear about this?

Comment: No my version 2 of my code gives same error and no quotes :)

Comment: What happens if you do `$PowerBIToken = Get-PowerBIAccessToken -AsString` and use it like `Clear-PBITableRows -authToken $PowerBIToken`

Comment: Unfortunately same error (403) Forbidden.
The token still goes over multiple rows.

Comment: Then how about `$PowerBIToken = (Get-PowerBIAccessToken -AsString) -split '\r?\n' -join ''` ?

Comment: Same issue. Found out in one example from the author that it seems that I did it correct but it still doesn't work. https://github.com/DevScope/powerbi-powershell-modules/blob/master/Modules/PowerBIPS/Samples/PowerBIPS.Sample.Get.ps1